# CSS: make drop-down menu as wide as top bar

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I've made a top bar that contains drop-down MENU button on the right side. But this drop-down content has exactly the same size (width) as my MENU button. Finally - my goal is to make this drop-down content as wide as the top bar is.

My HTML code looks like this:

```
<div id="top-bar">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">MENU</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link</a>
      <a href="#">Link</a>
      <a href="#">Link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And more important part - CSS:

```
#top-bar{
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  float: left;
  width:100%;
  height:40px;
  background-color: black;
}
.dropbtn {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 12px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdown {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 10px 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    left: 0;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

If you want to see how does it look like [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/bimbochobot/69uts0dr/2/) is jsFiddle link.
Don't you have any idea how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move `position: relative` from `.dropdown` to `#top-bar`.

By doing this, `.dropdown-content` will calculate `width` according to the nearest element with `position: relative` i.e `#top-bar`.

```css
#top-bar{
  position: relative;
  height:40px;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  float: right;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 10px 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="top-bar">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">MENU</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link</a>
      <a href="#">Link</a>
      <a href="#">Link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @PetrBečka I've updated css and removed unnecessary properties.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's what you want

```css
#top-bar{
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  float: left;
  width:100%;
  height:40px;
  background-color: black;
}

.dropbtn {
  display: block;
  float: right;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 12px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    float: left;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 10px 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    left: 0;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="top-bar">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">MENU</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link</a>
      <a href="#">Link</a>
      <a href="#">Link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/69uts0dr/3/